# Sum matching entries in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

In this database I need to find the total amount that each customer paid for books in a category, and then sort them by their customer ID. The code appears to run correctly but I end up with approximately 20 extra rows than I should, although the sum appears to be correct in the right rows.

The customer ID is part of `customer`, but is not supposed to appear in the `select` clause, when I try and `ORDER BY` it, I get strange errors. The DB engine is DB2.

```
SELECT distinct customer.name, book.cat, sum(offer.price) AS COST
FROM offer

INNER JOIN purchase ON purchase.title=offer.title
INNER JOIN customer ON customer.cid=purchase.cid
INNER JOIN member ON member.cid=customer.cid
INNER JOIN book ON book.title=offer.title

WHERE
member.club=purchase.club
AND member.cid=purchase.cid AND purchase.club=offer.club
GROUP BY customer.name, book.cat;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should fix your `join` conditions to include the ones in the `where` clause (between table relationships usually fit better into an `on` clause).

`SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never appropriate with a `GROUP BY`.

But those are not your question.  You can use an aggregation function:

```
GROUP BY customer.name, book.cat
ORDER BY MIN(customer.id)
```